# A question about the argument part of impedance

Tags: capacitor, impedance

The definition of impedance is Z = V/I. I'm trying to understand the idea behind the argument part of the impedance concept in a capacitor.

First here is what I know briefly so far:

I will begin this by assuming the voltage across the capacitor is sinusoidal as:

```
Vcap = A* sin(w*t)
```

one can also write:

```
Vcap = Im{A* e.^(j*w*t)} * (1/j) //complex representation
```

Current through the capacitor Icap is the derivative of the voltage so that:

```
Icap = C*dV/dt

Icap = C*A* w*cos(w*t)

Icap = Re{A* e.^(j*w*t)} * C*w //complex representation
```

So we can therefore write the impedance Zcap as:

```
Zcap = (1/j*w*C) *  [Im{e.^(j*w*t)}] ./ [Re{e.^(j*w*t)}]
```

or one can also write the following:

```
Zcap = Vcap./Icap

Zcap = (1/w*C)*tan(w*t) 

tan(w*t) = -j * Im{e.^(j*w*t)}] ./ [Re{e.^(j*w*t)}]
```

My question is about the impedance's argument part:

```
Zcap = (1/w*C)*tan(w*t)
```

or

```
Zcap = (1/j*w*C) *  [Im{e.^(j*w*t)}] ./ [Re{e.^(j*w*t)}]
```

Reactance is defined as `Xcap = |Zcap| = 1/(w*C)`

But to hold the above equation the following must be true:

```
|tan(w*t)| = 1
```

or

```
| -j * Im{e.^(j*w*t)}] ./ [Re{e.^(j*w*t)}] | = 1
```

How can they be equal to one where they are time dependent?

Is reactance the maximum impedance?

Is there a way to illustrate or explain the argument part of the impedance in this case?

**EDIT:**

My confusion comes from the following fact:

[image]

In the above plot red represents the voltage, blue is the current accross the capacitor. They have 90 degrees phase difference.

And since we defined Z =V/I:

Look at now the green encircled region where voltage becomes max and current becomes zero at the same time. If we freeze the time at that moment, as you see V/I goes to infinity. What is going on here?

The impedance Z = V/I changing by time, even goes to infinity sometimes; yet we associate the reactance with what??

Comment: A guide to increase readability: http://math.stackexchange.com/help/notation

Comment: What is Re ? You introduce this term with no expaination.

Comment: @JImDearden Re means the real part of the complex exponential in this context. Im is the imaginary part.

Comment: But for a capacitor (or inductor) there is no real part as the current is 90 degrees out of phase with the voltage.

Comment: I used complex representation to introduce j

Comment: go back to the definitions that you wrote above for I and V as exponential complex functions in time. Then divide them. Viola! If you use cos(), you only have the real part, and that does go to zero sometimes.

Comment: I suppose you should define a capacitor model that you want to consider. Also, reactance is always an imaginary part and not Xcap = |Zcap| as you stated above.

Comment: The expression under 'one can also write' is wrong in several ways, e.g. \$Im(x+jy) = y\$ and not \$jy\$. Also numerous errors in converting between cartesian and polar co-ordinates throughout. You should use Latex to format the equations - they are very difficult to read in their current form.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> The impedance Z = V/I changing by time, even goes to infinity
>   sometimes; yet we associate the reactance with what??

The impedance \$Z\$ of a circuit element is the ratio of the *phasor* voltage across and *phasor* current through, not the ratio of the time domain voltage and current.

So, for example,

$$v_C(t) = A\sin(\omega t) = \Re\{-jAe^{j\omega t}\}$$
$$i_C(t) = \omega C\; A\cos(\omega t) = \Re\{\omega C\;Ae^{j\omega t}\}$$

The phasor representation of the voltage and current are just the (constant) complex numbers multiplying \$e^{j \omega t}\$ thus, the *phasor* voltage and currents are

$$V_c = -jA$$
$$I_c = \omega C A $$

The impedance of the capacitor is then

$$Z_c = \frac{V_c}{I_c} = \frac{-jA}{\omega C A} = \frac{1}{j\omega C}$$

and so the reactance, the imaginary part of the impedance, of the capacitor is

$$X_c = -\frac{1}{\omega C} $$

Comment: How can we define the impedance Zcap in time domain?

Comment: 'Impedance' has no meaning in the time domain